# Basic logical math properties

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

So I have a question in logical math.

I want to know how to simplify the next expression and maybe understand the rule.

So I have those 3 atomic formulas $A,B,C$  (if there is a way)

$$ \neg(\neg(A\lor \neg(A\lor B))\lor \neg(B\lor C))$$

I was told that is actually  $ ((A\land \neg B)\lor (B\land C))$

Thanks in advanced !!

Comment: I rewrote to match standard symbolism and LaTeX and hope this is wat you intended ...

Comment: What do you mean when you claim that $\neg(\neg(A\lor \neg(A\lor B))\lor \neg(B\lor C))$? That this is true no matter what $A$, $B$ and $C$ are? Or simply that the first expression simplifies into the second?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yea !! This is what I meant

Comment: @JackM no, it depend on the value of A,B,C.

Comment: @wantToLearn Hm, but if so the latter expression can be further smpliied to $A\land B\land C$

Answer (score 6):

$$\neg(\neg(A\lor \neg(A\lor B))\lor \neg(B\lor C))$$
Use DeMorgan's !!

By DeMorgan's, we know that

- $\lnot (P \lor Q) \equiv (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$.
- $\lnot (P\land Q) \equiv (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)$.

Try to use this multiple times...and see what this gives you.

$$\neg(\neg(A\lor \neg(A\lor B))\lor \neg(B\lor C)) $$
$$\equiv \lnot \lnot (A \lor (\lnot A\land  \lnot B)] \land (B \lor C) \tag{(2) DM I}$$
$$\equiv [A \lor (\lnot A\land \lnot B)] \land (B\lor C)\tag{(3) DN}$$

*Note: In the first line, I used DeMorgan's twice. In the second line,} I applied double negation: $$\lnot \lnot P \equiv P\tag{Double Negation, DN}$$

Now, we can apply the distributive "laws": $$P \land (Q \lor R) \equiv (P \land Q) \lor (P\land R)\tag{DL I}$$

$$P \lor (Q \land R) \equiv (P\lor Q) \land (P \lor R)\tag{DL II}$$

---

$$[A \lor (\lnot A\land \lnot B)] \land (B\lor C)) \equiv ((A\lor \lnot A)\land (A \lor \lnot B))\land (B\lor C))$$

Knowing that $A \lor \lnot A \equiv T$, we can omit $A \lor \lnot A$ *without losing any information whatsoever.* That leaves us with

$$ ((A\lor \lnot A)\land (A \lor \lnot B))\land (B\lor C))\equiv \bf (A \lor \neg B)\land (B\lor C)$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint !! really helpful, but I only reached : $((A \lor (\neg A \land \neg B )) \land (B \lor C))$                     how Do I continue from here what can I do ?

Comment: Thank u very much !! you helped me a lot !!

Comment: You're very welcome! Just say the "word" if you have any questions! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Nice feedback and write - up +1

Answer (score 1):

One (maybe not elegant, but definitely leading to success) way is to use truth tables and compare. Here you'd need to check all $8$ combinations of truth and falsehood among the three atomics.

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$ \neg(\neg(A\lor \neg(A\lor B))\lor \neg(B\lor C))$$

By DeMorgan's Law, this becomes:

$$ (\neg\neg(A\lor \neg(A\lor B))\land \neg\neg(B\lor C))$$

By the double negation law,

$$ ((A\lor \neg(A\lor B))\land (B\lor C))$$

By DeMorgan's Law,

$$ ((A\lor (\neg A\land \neg B))\land (B\lor C))$$

By the distributive law,

$$ ((A\lor \neg A)\land (A \lor \neg B))\land (B\lor C))$$

Using the Tautology law,

$$  (A \lor \neg B)\land (B\lor C)$$

Which is what I got, though it seems to be "backwards" to what you have

Comment: You're very welcome. I am happy to hear that.